# Get Youtube Channel Thumbnail from API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am working on Youtube API v3 .. I was succeeded to get videos of a Youtube Channel. and then I was trying to get the thumbnail of a channel but couldn't be able to do that... can someone here have any solution for this ? I think the API doesn't return thumbnail of a channel

NOTE : I need the Thumbnail of a channel not the videos inside..

**code:**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=API_KEY&channelId=CHANNEL_ID&
part=snippet&order=date&maxResults=40
```

Comment: RTM: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#snippet.thumbnails.%28key%29 - default – The default thumbnail image. The default thumbnail for a video – or a resource that refers to a video, such as a playlist item or search result – is 120px wide and 90px tall. *The default thumbnail for a channel is 88px wide and 88px tall.*

Comment: but how will you get that.. JSON response is not showing any default for channel in response..

Comment: Show the code your using.

Comment: paste the above link in address bar with API key and channel Id... you will be able to see the response in JSON format

Comment: You're absolutely correct. But as already pointed out, your using `search`, when you should be using `channels` endpoint. RTM..

Comment: can you paste the link here with required parameters and endpoints.. so i'll be to see how that works